# Beamer: how to change author color

Tags: beamer

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\definecolor{BluPantoneCoated541}{HTML}{003C71}

\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=BluPantoneCoated541}

\title{An interesting topic}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I set the author's color to be equal to an unfocused section in the sidebar?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick the right color with `\setbeamercolor*{author in sidebar}{parent=section in sidebar shaded}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Hannover}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\definecolor{BluPantoneCoated541}{HTML}{003C71}

\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=BluPantoneCoated541}
\setbeamercolor*{author in sidebar}{parent=section in sidebar shaded}

\title{An interesting topic}
\author{Me}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{A section}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]